# Mysql table with more than one Auto-Incremented column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table with the following structure:

```
 id |  number |  text
----------------------
  1 |    1    |  test
```

in which, **id** is my primary key with auto increment value. I want to make number as auto increment value too. Is it possible to have more than one auto increment column in one table?

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin you can set an autoincrement on each column. And if your numbre is equell to your id ti's not very usefull

Comment: but i'm getting error >> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible.There can be only one auto-increment column and it must be defined as a key in MySQL.
But You can do it by using `trigger` for detail go this link  [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: The link you mentioned is not found. Please check this.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

Comment: @AhmadSharif I have update the link please check it now and thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

```
create trigger nameTrigger before insert on tables
for each row
begin
  DECLARE newNumber unsigned default 0;
  SELECT Max(number)+1 INTO newNumber FROM myTable WHERE id = new.id;
  UPDATE myTable SET number = newNumber WHERE id = new.id;
end
```